# Insert trigonometric function to org file

Tags: org-mode, math

When inserting trigonometric function or other mathematics formulas,
I usually insert an image to org file as

[image: trigonometric function]

Is it possible writing such a formula to org.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, by using Latex and preview that. Have a read at the [org-mode manual org-latex-preview section](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-latex-preview.html).

There are embedded formulae like `$\sin(r) = 3\sin\left(\frac r3\right)-4\sin^3\left(\frac r3\right)$` or displayed formulae like

```latex
\begin{align}
  \sin(r) = 3\sin\left(\frac r3\right)-4\sin^3\left(\frac r3\right)
  \label{eq:MyFirstLaTeXEquation}
\end{align}
```

You can refer to the label in the last equation by `\eqref{eq:MyFirstLaTeXEquation}`.

[LaTeX syntax](https://latex.org/forum/app.php/page/about-latex) is used in the formulae.